# C# Creating properties at runtime

Tags: c#

I have a folder containing some sound files. What I would like to do is to, at runtime, fill a class (SoundFileNames.c) with both their full path and filename. Preferably I would like it to be so that if I have the file "MySound.wav" in said folder, I could index it like this: SoundFileNames.MySound, which would produce C:..\MySound.wav.
I don't know if this is the best solution, or even possible. How can I achieve this? Any help is greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Whilst it's possible to create dynamic objects with properties like this, you're probably better off storing the information in something like a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so you could access the paths via `SoundFileNames["MySound"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple SoundPathProvider that you could use as a template to arrive at the desired behavior.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace SoundProvider
{
    public class SoundPathProvider
    {
        private readonly string _sourcePath;

        public SoundPathProvider(string sourcePath)
        {
            _sourcePath = sourcePath;
        }

        public string GetSoundPath(string soundName)
        {
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(_sourcePath);
            var targetSound = files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Split('\\').Last() == soundName);
            if (targetSound != null)
                return Path.Combine(_sourcePath, soundName);
            else 
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Sound '{0}' Not Found in '{1}'", soundName, _sourcePath));
        }
    }
}
```

And template Unit Tests that can help you develop the functionality.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace SoundProvider
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SoundPathProviderTests
    {
        [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
        [TestMethod]
        public void SoundPathProvider_GetNonExistentSoundPath_ThrowsException()
        {
            var provider = new SoundPathProvider("C:\\Temp\\SoundProviderSource");

            var soundPath = provider.GetSoundPath("NonExistentSound.wav");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SoundPathProvider_GetExistingSoundPath_ThrowsException()
        {
            var provider = new SoundPathProvider("C:\\Temp\\SoundProviderSource");

            var soundPath = provider.GetSoundPath("SampleSound.wav");

            Assert.AreEqual("C:\\Temp\\SoundProviderSource\\SampleSound.wav", soundPath);
        }
    }
}
```